# reverse results of php recursive function

Tags: php

I have wrote a php function to show the categories, all works find but the echo show as reversed like this (Chairs / Furniture / Products ), but i need it to be reversed to look like this (Products / Furniture / Chairs  )

```
    function sitemap($id) { 
    $query_rsCategoryId = "SELECT * FROM categories 
    WHERE category_id = '".$id."'";
    $rsCategoryId = mysql_query($query_rsCategoryId, $connection);
    $row_rsCategoryId = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCategoryId);
    $parent = $row_rsCategoryId['category_parent'];

    echo '<li><span class="divider">/</span>
    <a href="products.php?category_id='.$row_rsCategoryId['category_id'].'">
    '.$row_rsCategoryId['category_name_en'].' </a>
    </li>';

    if ($parent == 0) {
    exit;
    } else {
    return sitemap($parent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than echoing the result, build an array of the recursive results, then you can reverse the order of that array, followed by looping through the array displaying the results

Comment: Place the echo AFTER the recursive function call. (Also save the return value into a variable and return it in the end. But it doesn't seem you do anything with it. Also invert the condition: if $parent != 0 then sitemap($parent))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modify your code a bit...

```
function sitemap($id) { 
   $query_rsCategoryId = "SELECT * FROM categories 
   WHERE category_id = '".$id."'";
   $rsCategoryId = mysql_query($query_rsCategoryId, $connection);
   $row_rsCategoryId = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCategoryId);
   $parent = $row_rsCategoryId['category_parent'];


   if ($parent != 0) {
      sitemap($parent);
      echo '<li><span class="divider">/</span>';
   } else {
      echo '<li>';
   }

    echo '<a href="products.php?category_id='.$row_rsCategoryId['category_id'].'">
   '.$row_rsCategoryId['category_name_en'].' </a>
   </li>';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try to use order by desc in your query

```
SELECT * FROM categories 
WHERE category_id = '".$id."' ORDER BY category_name_en DESC
```

Comment: That won't work, he is fetching each category in a separate query.